# linking libc with JNI code on embedded Linux platform (GuruPlug)

Tags: linux, linker, java-native-interface, libc

I'm trying to compile a simple JNI application on an embedded Linux platform (a GuruPlug computer), but for some reason it's not linking to libc properly. The Java program I'm compiling is called Test.java:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().printMessage();
    }

    public native void printMessage();
}
```

The implementation of printMessage() is in Test.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Test.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_printMessage(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    printf("Message 123...\n");
}
```

I'm compiling Test.c with the following command on a bash shell:

```
gcc -g -shared -static -lc -Wl,-soname,libTest.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ Test.c -o libTest.so
```

When I run the above command, I get the error message "R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object". The full error message is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.5/../../../libc.a(dl-tsd.o)(.text+0x18): R_ARM_TLS_LE32 relocation not permitted in shared object
```

Despite the error message, the JNI .so file is still written by the compiler, but running the Java application gives the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jni/libTest.so: /usr/lib/jni/libTest.so: unexpected reloc type 0x03
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1750)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
        at Test.<clinit>(Test.java:3)
Could not find the main class: Test. Program will exit.
```

Does anybody have any idea how to go about fixing this? Admittedly, the above code is a toy example, but I need to get a real JNI library compiling on this platform, and the real JNI library depends on libc. I can't seem to solve this basic issue of linking libc with a JNI library. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `gcc -g -shared -static -lc -Wl,-soname,libTest.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ Test.c -o libTest.so`

There are several problems with the command line above:

- the `-shared` and `-static` flags are mutually exclusive, and the second overrides the first
- when linking shared libraries, you want `-fPIC` on most architectures
- the `-lc` is in the wrong place (should follow your sources, not precede them), and is not necessary anyway: gcc will add it automatically
- you don't strictly need the `-soname` either; it's just useless clutter

The correct command then is:

```
gcc -g -shared -fPIC -I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux \
  Test.c -o libTest.so
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. I figured out a really long and ugly command to do this, but what you wrote looks much nicer. (I was going to answer my own question as soon as the 8 hour window was up; I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question before that.)

The command I came up with before was this: `gcc -g -shared -static -Wl,-soname,libTest.so -Wl,-Bstatic -lc -Wl,-Bdynamic -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/ -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux/ Test.c -o libTest.so`

It worked, but it was definitely too verbose.